# Python find pairs of socks from a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, loops, for-loop

I'm pretty new to programming and python. I was asked to find out a pair of socks from a given list of numbers.
My question was - "There is a large pile of socks that must be paired by color. Given an array of integers representing the color of each sock, determine how many pairs of socks with matching colors there are."
Sample Input

```
STDIN                       Function
-----                       --------
9                           n = 9
10 20 20 10 10 30 50 10 20  ar = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20]
```

Sample Output

```
3
```

So my logic was pretty simple, iterate through the list, take a number, compare it with others. If two same numbers are found, count them as a pair and remove them from the list. Then do the same untiil none are left

```
# Complete the sockMerchant function below.
def sockMerchant(n, ar):
    print(ar)
    l=[]
    result=0
    for i in ar:
        a=i
        c=0
        print("a",a)#line for checking
        ar.remove(i)
        l=ar
        print("ar",ar)#line for checking
        print("l", l)#line for checking
        for j in l:
            f=l.index(j)
            print("index", f))#line for checking
            print("j",j))#line for checking
            if j == a:
                c=c+1
                print("c",c))#line for checking
                ar.remove(j)
                print("ar2",ar))#line for checking
             

             
    result=c/2
    print("c2",c))#line for checking
    return result
n=9
ar=[10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20]
sockMerchant(n, ar)
```

Please ignore the line of code beside the comments. They are just there to see the control flow. and here is my output:

```
[10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20]
a 10
ar [20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20]
l [20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20]
index 0
j 20
index 0
j 20
index 2
j 10
c 1
ar2 [20, 20, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20]
index 3
j 30
index 4
j 50
index 2
j 10
c 2
ar2 [20, 20, 30, 50, 10, 20]
a 20
ar [20, 30, 50, 10, 20]
l [20, 30, 50, 10, 20]
index 0
j 20
c 1
ar2 [30, 50, 10, 20]
index 1
j 50
index 2
j 10
index 3
j 20
c 2
ar2 [30, 50, 10]
a 10
ar [30, 50]
l [30, 50]
index 0
j 30
index 1
j 50
c2 0
```

Comment: Do you have a question? If you want a code review, [codereview.se] is the place to go.

Comment: Why are you re-assigning variables to different values to much? This is unnececairy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is full of wonderful utils that can be helpful. [Counters](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from collections can be used for counting how many socks of each color you got and then you just divide by 2 to get the number of pairs.

```
from collections import Counter
from typing import List

def sock_merchant(socks: List[int]) -> int:
    counter = Counter(ar)
    return sum((count // 2 for count in counter.values())
```

Initializing counter with an array will give you something that looks like

```
Counter({10: 4, 20: 3, 30: 1, 50: 1})
```

which is the value from the array (i.e color of the sock) and the number of times it occurs in the array.
Like with normal dicts, counters also have a `.values()` methods that will give you only the values, and since we want the number of pairs, we take the sum of the values after doing integer division on each of them.